# how to manage two spinner setOnItemSelectedListener android

Tags: android, spinner, android-spinner

I used two spinners in same fragment I want when the first spinner will complete its task then only the setOnItemSelectedListener will call for the second spinner.

**Issue:** But the issue is setOnItemSelectedListener is called on same time for both the spinners.How can I manage that. :(

**What I want to do:** I want to draw a graph on page load spinner 1 will darw a different graph and spinner 2 will draw a different graphon page load.

Any help will be Appreciated.

Comment: Paste some of your code so that we can help you

Comment: Hi Apoorv I have added my code below.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you have same setOnItemSelectedListener  for both the spinners.

Have structure like this:

```
spinner1.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() 
{
    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parentView, View selectedItemView, int position, long id) 
    {

        func1();
    }

    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parentView) 
    {
        Toast.makeText(topThis, "herf", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
});



spinner2.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() 
{
    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parentView, View selectedItemView, int position, long id) 
    {
        func2();
    }

    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parentView) 
    {
        Toast.makeText(topThis, "herf", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
});



private void func1()
{
//do task of spinner1
}
    private void func2()
    {
    //your task for second spinner
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
spinnerLeft = (Spinner) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.spinner_left);
    dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(),android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, arrayList);
    dataAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    spinnerLeft.setAdapter(dataAdapter);

spinerRight = (Spinner) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.spinner_right);
    rightSpinnerAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(),android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, arrayList);
    rightSpinnerAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    spinerRight.setAdapter(rightSpinnerAdapter);
```

That is my two spinner that I calle d on onActivityCreated.

```
spinerRight.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                int position, long arg3) { 
// here I called a method to download a chart and showing below 1st spinner
```

AppGlobals.getInstance().checkSpinner = 1;
     }

```
private void addListenerOnSpinnerLeftItemSelection() {
    spinnerLeft.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                int position, long arg3) {
 //here I m called the same method to download and show chart below 2nd spinner
```

AppGlobals.getInstance().checkSpinner = 1;
     }

But the before completing the first spinner functionality the second spinner called. I have but the int value so that when both the spinner's called the int value will tell the difference.

```
if (AppGlobals.getInstance().checkSpinner == 1) {
        chartArea = (LinearLayout) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.chart);
    } else if (AppGlobals.getInstance().checkSpinner == 0) {
        chartArea = (LinearLayout) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.pie_chart);
    }
```